# How to get session wise performance indicators(CPU/IO/Memory) history info in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, performance

I worked in Teradata Performance engineering before. In Teradata, we had a view like pdcrinfo.DBQLogTbl_hst which contains session wise CPU I/O info along with Query Text for last 3-4 months as configured by TD DBA.

Now I am very new to Oracle. It would be great if somebody could provide a similar kind of View name or a Query ,by joining system tables, through which 
we can get Session wise CPU I/O and query info at least for last 7 days.
Already tried to form 1 query as below:

```
Select substr(c.sid || ',' || c.serial#,0,15) sid,   c.USERNAME,c.PROGRAM,c.MACHINE,c.OSUSER,
    c.LOGON_TIME,c.TERMINAL,c.sql_address,c.sql_hash_value,
    ROUND (sum(b.CPU_TIME)) "CPU Usage",
    cast(b.sql_fulltext as VARCHAR(1000)) Query 
from 
     v$session c, sys.V_$SQL b 
where 
     b.address=c.sql_address and c.sql_hash_value=b.hash_value  and c.USERNAME='XXX_USER'     
group by substr(c.sid || ',' || c.serial#,0,15),c.USERNAME,c.PROGRAM,
     c.MACHINE,c.OSUSER,c.LOGON_TIME,c.TERMINAL,
    c.sql_address,c.sql_hash_value,
    cast(b.sql_fulltext as VARCHAR(1000))
Order by c.LOGON_TIME,sid,c.sql_address,c.sql_hash_value
```

But it seems v$session is having only current session info of XXX_USER not the history of all the sessions of XXX_USER.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`  perhaps?

See here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_1007.htm#REFRN30299

If this doesn't help, query the `dict` view for a full list of all views and what they show to pick out one that might have what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM dict WHERE comments LIKE '%HISTORY%';
```

Another option would be to use Grid Control AWR reports if you have that set up. It's a webby DBA tool.